# SparkHDInsights cluster when using blobproperties.getcreatedtime is not working

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-blob-storage, azure-hdinsight

I am using SparkHDInsights cluster to run a jar using spark-submit command. I have used

```
libraryDependencies += "com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-storage" % "8.1.0"
```

in sbt file.

The program works completely fine in local. Only when trying running on cluster its creating exception. I believe its using library `"com.microsoft.azure" % "azure-storage" % "5.3.0"` which could be by default option in Azure HDI cluster.

The program snippet is :

```
val blob = blobInDir.asInstanceOf[CloudBlockBlob]  
var blobtime = blob.getProperties.getCreatedTime().getTime
```

I am getting an error like:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobProperties.getCreatedTime()Ljava/util/Date;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your error information, I tried to review the source code of Azure Storage for Java to find out the issue reason. Then, I found there is no method named `getCreatedTime` for the `BlobProperties` when the `azure-storage` version is lower than `v7.1.0-Preview`. Meanwhile, the `azure-storage` library is a dependency of `hadoop-azure` on HDInsight, and its `7.0.0` version be required the latest version [`3.2.0`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-azure/3.2.0) of `hadoop-azure` as below.

[image]

So you can not fix the issue via upgrade HDInsight, but you can use your jar files to cover the related jar files in HDInsight via set the below configure options to change the priority of classpath load to make your program run like in local.

1. Set `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` value is `true`, please see the offical meaning below.

[image]

2. Set `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` value is `true`, please see the offical meaning below.

[image]

The options above you can set in `spark.conf` file or pass via `spark-submit`.

Comment: Thanks Sir. I have tried using --driver-class-path along with spark-submit. It worked as I have enforced usage of desired updated jar.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this issue.